# getting custom attributes defined in openApi spec

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I have created a managed service in google endpoints by defining an `openApi.json` file of my service.

Along with service details I have added custom attributes in my `openApi.json` using `x-***` keys, with this i get a valid openApi spec and have successfully deployed a version using the command `gcloud endpoints services deploy openApi.json`

Now when i fetch that configuration using the command `gcloud endpoints configs describe --service=SERVICE VERSION`, the config I get is missing those custom attributes I added.

How can I get the original openApi spec(along with those custom attributes) from gcloud endpoints?

Comment: Can you share example of custom attributes you are using?

Comment: @vitooh What example do you need? It's a custom attribute, it can be anything. This is an example of custom Google attributes:- https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions and this is official docs of adding custom attributes in swagger:- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#vendorExtensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a Google ticket and found out that this feature is not provided by Google as of now.
Google only keep those attributes of swagger specs which are needed in Google Endpoints.

I have raised a request for this fix and if you want this feature on priority you can star/comment on it here:- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169126996